# Login to Stack Exchange account doesn't use HTTPS/SSL?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, login

I have created a Stack Exchange account and have found that the login page does not use HTTPS/SSL.

I do not like to login without this protection, so is there a way to log in with HTTPS/SSL?

Comment: All login links uses HTTPS/SSL; where you found it which do not uses https/ssl?

Comment: OK this is just a guess: May be you have clicked on login link at the top in SO or any other SE site. Which have take you to the page something like [this](http://writers.stackexchange.com/users/login). This page do not use HTTPS/SSL but this is also not the page where you enter your password. This is just to select the account type by which you want to login. After you select account type it will take you to the respective site which uses HTTPS/SSL. SO don't worry your information will be secure no one is gonna hack your account.... :)

Comment: @Harry is what you say still valid now that SO is an OpenID provider, though?

Comment: Ah, fair enough, it is. SO's OpenID signup is https.

Answer (score 12):

Stack Overflow's OpenID signup/login page is indeed not on a `https://` URL, but it contains an `iframe` element that holds the login and signup forms. That iframe *is* encrypted:

[image]

it admittedly looks a bit misleading, but everything is in order here.

Comment: you mean to say there is a login link which is not HTTPS?

Comment: @Harry no. Edited to clarify

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Unfortunately I cannot vote up yet.

Comment: No, everything is ***not*** in order.  If a page is asking me to login, it should be and ***appear*** properly secured.  Otherwise, how do I, the user, know that tomorrow everything is *still* in order??

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey, exactly

Comment: We are discussing this to a greater extend over here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202518/does-stack-overflow-use-ssl-during-the-log-in-process

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the path is HTTPS now, as it should be in the final version. We'll be deploying `secure`-only cookies soon.